# Wrap/Break list items in two ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

Trying to Wrap/Break list items and add class by replace text from list items, example below?

Original Html:

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>

        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*I trying to make Output like this:*

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <ul class="textone">
        <li><span class="label"> textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> textone</span> Test Content</li>

    </ul> <!-- Break part 1 -->

    <ul class="texttwo">
        <!-- Break part 2 -->
        <li><span class="label"> texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label"> texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to split it in to multiple groups and add class to new parent `ul`(output Html example) by replace text from `class="label"`

Here is what I tried:

```
var arr = []; // array to store `li` elements
var widget = $(".widget-content");

$(".widget-content li").each(function(index, el) {
  var html = el.outerHTML;
  // number at `label` text
  var curr = $(".label", this).text().trim().slice(-1);
  if (arr[curr - 1]) {
    arr[curr - 1].push(html)
  } else {
    arr[curr - 1] = [html];
  }
});

widget.html(""); // remove existing `html`

$.each(arr, function(key, val) {
  var li = val.join("");
  $(".widget-content").append($("<ul/>", {
    html: li,
    "class":$(li).eq(0).find(".label").text().trim()
  }))
})
```

Not working, Please check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yn60j368/5/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, are you trying to break the list on every three items, in half, or in some other way? It's not really clear

Comment: You're sure it's not *by the content of the span*, as that's what it seems like

Comment: I want Output like second HTML example, get class from `span class="label"` by replace text content. Check the second HTML example. I want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, moving the LI's to new parents, based on the text in `.label`

```js
var widget  = $('.widget-content'),
    ul      = widget.find('ul'),
    classes = ['left', 'right'];

ul.find('li').each(function() {
    var span   = $(this).find('.label');
    var text   = span.text();
    var parent = widget.find('[data-parent="'+text+'"]');
    
    if ( parent.length === 0 ) {
     widget.append( $('<ul class="'+classes.shift()+'" data-parent="'+text+'" />').append(this) )
    } else {
     parent.append(this)
    }
    ul.remove();
});
```

```css
.left  {color: green}
.right {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-content">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>

        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, want simple change: how to give pacific Class name to new parent `ul`.? Don't text replace from `class="label"`

Comment: I meant change for different custom Class name to different parent 'ul'

Comment: So what classnames would you like to use then, you need to be specific and explain what you want

Comment: first `ul` will be class name `left` and second `ul` will be class name `right`

Comment: Edited the answer to add those classes, and make it easier to change them to whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

Following your code (same principle), this is another solution:

```js
var $widget = $('.widget-content');
var elements = {};

$widget.find('li').each(function () {
  var key = $(this).find('span').text();
  // If key is not defined yet, we define an Array
  elements[key] = typeof elements[key] === 'undefined' ? [] : elements[key];
  // Adds the content of the <li>
  elements[key].push($(this).text());
}).parent().remove(); // Clears the <ul>

$.each(elements, function(index, values) {
  var $ul = $('<ul/>').addClass(index);
  $.each(values, function () {
   $ul.append($('<li/>').text(this));
  });
  $widget.append($ul);
});
```

```css
 .textone {
   color: red;
 }
 
 .texttwo {
   color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget-content">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>

        <li><span class="label">texttwo</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
        <li><span class="label">textone</span> Test Content</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how to give pacific Class name to new parent `ul`.? Don't text replace from `class="label"`

Comment: Just change `index` value on line `var $ul = $('<ul/>').addClass(index);` with your `pacific` class.

Comment: I meant change for different custom Class name to different parent 'ul'

Answer (score 1):

jquery `wrapAll()` is another short & sweet way.

```
// get unique texts
var uniTxt = [];
$('.label').text(function(index,txt){
  ( $.inArray(txt,uniTxt) > -1) ? null : uniTxt.push( txt ) ;
});

// rearrange items
$(uniTxt).each(function(index, className){
  $('li').filter(':contains('+className+')')
  .unwrap()                             // remove initial parent ul 
  .wrapAll('<ul class='+className+'>'); // wraps similar txt with a Ul & add class
});
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/CreativeCreate/pen/qZaWwz?editors=1010)